# How to perform search documents by items in subcollection

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I have such document structure:

```
{
    "Name" : "Hello world",
    "Parameters" : [ 
        {
            "Key" : 104,
            "Value" : 8
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : 112,
            "Value" : 20
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : 176,
            "Value" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : 179,
            "Value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : 180,
            "Value" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : 177,
            "Value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : 302,
            "Value" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : 303,
            "Value" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : 178,
            "Value" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : 181,
            "Value" : 2015
        }
    ]  
}
```

I need to select all objects where any parameter from parameters collections aplliyed to next conditions:

```
Expression<Func<SuperObject, bool>> newPred = x => x.Parameters.Any(
    p => p.Key == id 
    && p.Value >= min 
    && p.Value <= max
)
```

I tried to do that:

```
db.SuperObjects.find({ 
    Parameters: { 
        $elemMatch: { 
            Key: 104, 
            $and: [
                {Value: { $gte: 8 }}, 
                {Value: { $lte: 10 }}
            ] 
        } 
    } 
})
```

and it works in mongodb. But how to write such code in c#?

I tried it

```
filter = filter & builder.ElemMatch("Parameters", builder.Eq("Key", id) & builder.Gte("Value", min) & builder.Lte("Value", max));
```

It throws invalid cast exceptions because tried to cast parameters object to my SuperObject...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this query will not get you the parameters that satisfies your condition but the whole document itself. Is that what is intended? To select only a set of subdocument you must use group.

Having said that, You can create a filter based on your Mongo query directly like this

`BsonDocument filter = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>("{ Parameters: { $elemMatch: { Key: 104, $and: [{Value: { $gte: 8 }}, {Value: { $lte: 10 }}] } } })")`